# Shopify API Updating Fulfillments

Tags: shopify

I am writing a private app in Shopify with PHP.  I have been able to get most of the other access to the json data, however, I am having trouble with Fulfillments - specifically updating a single line-item.

I am using the api-skeleton (phpish)?

Here is my code (the process as described seems so simple):

```
$orderid = "1350520065";
$itemid = "2338134657";
$quantity = 1;

    $arguments = array(
           'fulfillment' => array(
           'tracking_number' => null,
           'notify_customer' => true,
           'line_items' =>  array(array('id' => $itemid, 'quantity' => 1))
        )
    );
    $response = $shopify('POST /admin/orders/' . $orderid . '/fulfillments.json', $arguments);
```

I am getting [line_items] => Required parameter missing or invalid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Skip the line items unless you are doing a partial fulfillment. If you are, then obviously you need a quantity. You forgot that it seems, hence your error of missing parameter.

Comment: I have done it with the quantity and without with the same error message.  It is also a "partial fulfillment" if the customer ordered 3 different things (5 shirts, 3 shorts, 1 blanket) and I am just delivering the 5 shirts.  In this case I think I am allowed to put in the id for the 5 shirts.

Comment: your script shows no quantity. So how is anyone supposed to know. My code works. You will have to figure it out yourself I guess.

Comment: I apologize if I seemed snarky, I'm just frustrated.  Here is my code with quantity and the resulting error.  Can you see any reason why I am having this problem.

 
 $orderid = "1069968321";
 $itemid = "1887500673";
 $quantity = 1;

 try
 {
  # Making an API request can throw an exception
  $arguments = array(
      'fulfillment' => array(
         'tracking_number' => null,
      'notify_customer' => true,
      'line_items' =>  array(array('id' => $itemid, 'quantity' => 1))
      )
  );

Array ( [errors] => Array ( [line_items] => Required parameter missing or invalid ) )  to David Lazar

Comment: I forget PHP... I guess array(array()) creates an array with an object... weird.. I dunno.. must be a PHP thing...

Answer (score 1):

Add a header 'Content-Type:application/json' to your POST. That worked for me.